# How can I validate and submit a form with jQuery if submit button has the name submit?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have this error in console "`Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function`"

Input button : `<input id="submit" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>`

I have found many solutions saying that name should not be submit. I have tried changing name but then form validations do not work on form submit and submit the form even if there are errors. What can be the issue?

jQuery:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    form.target="_self";
    form.action="submit.php";
    form.submit();
});

$('#form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == false)
            {alert('could not submit!')}
        }

        });

    }
});
```

UPDATE:
I want to disable the submit button if form is validated and submitted successfully, but if I add like this it disable the submit button without submitting the form.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
            $('#form').attr('action', 'submit.php');
            $('#form').submit();
        });
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#preview").attr("disabled", true);
                return true;
            }else{
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Comment: you yet to declare anything for `form` in submit click, maybe you need `document.form`?

Comment: @Se0ng11 I don't get you?

Comment: `form.target`, should be `document.form.target`? this goes to all the form inside the click event

Comment: Changing the name of the submit button shouldn't have any effect on validation. If it is, you need to figure out why and fix it. Maybe your validation code is looking for that name, you need to make it use the new name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $('#formId').attr('action', 'submit.php');
  $('#formId').attr('target', '_self');
  $('#formId').submit();

});
```

UPDATE

```
        if ($("#form_id").valid()) {
            $("#form_id").submit();
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#preview").attr("disabled", true);

        }else{
           return false;
        }
```

do something like this. it may give yo some idea. first validate form and then submit

Comment: The error's gone but now form could not be submitted :(

Comment: try removing target attr

Comment: your solution worked but I need one more help regarding this issue. I am updating the question please check.

Comment: not worked form gets validated on click thats why it disable the button but why it first not submit then disable the button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() { 
   /* your code here */
 });
```

Comment: still getting this Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function

Comment: Yes you can validate

Comment: still getting the error form.submit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $("#form");

            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == false) {
                        alert('could not submit!')
                    }
                    else {
                        //form.target = "_self";
                        //form.action = "submit.php";
                        form.submit();
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="form" action="test.html" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="" id="test" name="test" />
    <input id="submit" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Still this error in console on clicking submit Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function

Comment: @Haroon Can you update your question with the HTML you already implemented. For me there are no errors on `form.submit()`.